# Solving polynomials with compound angle formulae

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> > Solve $64x^6-96x^4+36x^2-3=0$ (Hint: Consider expanding $\cos 6\theta$ in terms of $\cos \theta$)

To solve this exercise I can simply derive an identity using de-Moivre theorem then shuffle the equation around. It turns out that substituting $x=\cos \theta$ reduces the equation to $\cos 6\theta = \frac{1}{2}$.

However, I'm wondering in the general case, is there any way to see this without the monster of a hint? In other words, given a polynomial, is there something I could look for in the coefficients that would make me think that deriving a compound angle formula may be a good idea?

Comment: You could look up the list of Chebyshev Polynomials for similarities.  In this case, check $T_6$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind, not hard to notice it is $2T_6-1$.

Comment: The equation is a cubic in $x^2$.  A cubic with 3 real roots can be solved with that trig substitution to get an expression for $cos 3\theta$.  So, if you were familiar with that well known method for solving a cubic, you wouldn't have needed the hint.

Answer (score 1):

It not always works in the general.

By the way, there are equations, which have nice real roots, but it not so easy to get these roots.

For example: $$x^5+x^4-12x^3-21x^2+x+5=0.$$
One of roots it's:

> $$2\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}{31}+\cos\frac{10\pi}{31}+\cos\frac{12\pi}{31}\right)$$

In another hand, there are equations, which we can solve by the similar idea, which you showed, but without any hint.

For example:

Solve the following equation.
$$8x(2x^2-1)(8x^4-8x^2+1)=1.$$